# Excel - VBA code to save range as pdf and using cell for file name

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code to save a selected range to be saved as PDF and using a cell as name for the file

But I have an error : Named argument not found at the last line :

```vb
Filemame:=path & pdfname & ".pdf
```

```vb
Sub save()
'Varriables
Dim SaveRng As Range
Dim pdfname As String
Dim path As String

'Setting range to be saved
Set SaveRng = Range("A5:O23")

'setting file name with a cell value
pdfname = Range("b10")

'path
path = "C:\Users\blablabla\"

'save the range as pdf
SaveRng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filemame:=path & pdfname & ".pdf"

End Sub
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to the [VBA documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/named-argument-not-found-error-448):

> A named argument may not be used in a procedure invocation unless it appears in the procedure definition. This error has the following cause and solution:
>
> You specified a named argument, but the procedure was not defined to accept an argument by that name. **Check the spelling of the argument name**.

(Emphasis mine)

The part of code giving error i as you stated is `Filemame:=path & pdfname & ".pdf`. The argument should be `Filename`. You mistyped `m` instead of `n` when typing. That's why you have the error.

Comment: Thanks for that! Shame on me.. haha

Comment: @Baguette If the answer has solved your question/problem, you can mark it as answered. Here is how to do it: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work